# Rails SQLException syntax errors (Model.where('date > ? AND date < ?, min, max)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I'm trying to look up the 'events' that fall between two datetimes.

```
    if (params[:timeMin].present? and params[:timeMax].present?)
      @events = Event.where('date > ? AND date < ?', params[:timeMin], params[:timeMax])
```

I keep getting a similar error and I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: SELECT "events".* FROM "events"  WHERE (date > '---
- (1i)
- ''2014''
','---
- (2i)
- ''1''
','---
- (3i)
- ''8''
','---
- (4i)
- ''14''
','---
- (5i)
- ''36''
' AND date < '---
- (1i)
- ''2014''
','---
- (2i)
- ''1''
','---
- (3i)
- ''13''
','---
- (4i)
- ''14''
','---
- (5i)
- ''36''
') ORDER BY events.created_at DESC
```

This is the line causing the issue in the view

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
```

Thanks

**Requested info**

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag events_path, :method => :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= datetime_select :timeMin, params[:timeMin] %>
    <%= datetime_select :timeMax, params[:timeMax] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search Near", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**Using solution from @CDub**

log when make request with dates that should return 2 (all) events -> none are returned (empty list)

```
Started GET "/events?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&timeMin%5B%281i%29%5D=2014&timeMin%5B%282i%29%5D=1&timeMin%5B%283i%29%5D=7&timeMin%5B%284i%29%5D=15&timeMin%5B%285i%29%5D=13&timeMax%5B%281i%29%5D=2014&timeMax%5B%282i%29%5D=1&timeMax%5B%283i%29%5D=13&timeMax%5B%284i%29%5D=15&timeMax%5B%285i%29%5D=13" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-13 18:13:45 -0800
Processing by EventsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"", "timeMin"=>{"(1i)"=>"2014", "(2i)"=>"1", "(3i)"=>"7", "(4i)"=>"15", "(5i)"=>"13"}, "timeMax"=>{"(1i)"=>"2014", "(2i)"=>"1", "(3i)"=>"13", "(4i)"=>"15", "(5i)"=>"13"}}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'BVjMjs3hJ1HV6udJzEg4-g' LIMIT 1
  Event Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (date > '2014-1-7 15:13:' AND date < '2014-1-13 15:13:') ORDER BY events.created_at DESC
  Rendered events/index.html.erb within layouts/application (9.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 53ms (Views: 52.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a `datetime_select` hash which will need to be parsed into a string.  One way of doing so is to do the following:

```
min_hash = params[:timeMin]
max_hash = params[:timeMax]

min_time_string = "#{min_hash['(1i)']}-#{min_hash['(2i)']}-#{min_hash['(3i)']} #{min_hash['(4i)']}:#{min_hash['(5i)']}:#{min_hash['(6i)']}"

max_time_string = "#{max_hash['(1i)']}-#{max_hash['(2i)']}-#{max_hash['(3i)']} #{max_hash['(4i)']}:#{max_hash['(5i)']}:#{max_hash['(6i)']}"
```

After this parsing, this should work:

```
@events = Event.where('date > ? AND date < ?', min_time_string, max_time_string)
```

Comment: Added the form that timeMin and timeMax are coming from. Hopefully this helps. Trying to figure out model search in rails

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it's still having issues. 1) if I set the dates where it should select events, it runs and returns no events (list is empty). 2) if I don't change either date (min == max) then it returns an error page "Request-URI Too Large". any ideas

Comment: Not sure I follow issue #1... What do the logs look like for both of those issues?

Comment: posted the log. Is there anyway to see what 'date' current is for each model

Comment: Sure.  You could stick it in a `Rails.logger.info` call and it'll print to the log.  I've updated my answer as well - there is no `6i`.  I've also used `Date.parse` to actually generate a legit `Date` object.  Give that a try.

Comment: I'm confused by what you did with Date.parse, what was changed and what does that do?

Comment: The `Date.parse` may not matter... and I removed the "seconds" part of the parsed timestamp...